# How to display all available choices of a manytomany field in django admin using filter_horizontal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models that have many to many relationship. One model consists of all possible choices and the other model can have some or all of those choices.

**These are the two models:**

```
class LanguageDomains(models.Model):
    DOMAIN_CHOICES=(
    ('Choice1', _(u'Choice1')),
    ('Choice2', _(u'Choice2')),
    ('Choice3', _(u'Choice3')),
    ('Choice4', _(u'Choice4')),
    )
    # There is many more choices in the actual code
    domains = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=DOMAIN_CHOICES, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.domains

class Revitalization(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Codes, related_name ='revitalization')
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    year_founded = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    some_domains = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageDomains, related_name='revitalization')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code.primary_name
```

My **admin.py:**

```
class RevitalizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code','id')
    filter_horizontal = ('language_domains',)
```

**This is what the admin console looks like:**
[image]

The question is, is there a way to populate the "Available language domains" list with all the DOMAIN_CHOICES from LanguageDomains model?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that will populate the LanguageDomains model table with all the available choices.

Depending on your use-case, if the sole purpose of LanguageDomains is to present multiple choices and it's not going to be edited in runtime look into using [django-multiselectfield](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield).

Comment: I will look into data migration but for now it seems like it just makes more sense to keep it the way I already have it and create a LangaugeDomains table manually and make table fields unique.

The problem with django-multiselectfield is that it saves data to CharField which is limited at 255 characters and amount of characters in my choices exceed this limit.